# Running Strapi CMS behind a Keycloak Gatekeeper

Tags: strapi, keycloak-gatekeeper

I'm trying to get Strapi running behind a Keycloak Gatekeeper. My problem now is that the Admin UI is broken, because it uses the `Authorization` header to include a custom JWT. Keycloak Gatekeeper also uses the `Authorization` header with its own JWT. Is there any way to either a) disable authentication in Strapi so that it doesn't send the `Authorization` header or b) make strapi use another header for its JWT?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Similar example that was never merged take a look [here](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/pull/3161)